# LaTex Skipping Figure Counting

Tags: numbering, longtable, csv

I'm having trouble with the `\label` feature in figure environments. Initially, the code I was working with would label Figure 1 in Section 4 as *Figure 41*. I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865036/using-a-single-count-for-figures-and-tables-in-latex?rq=1, and I implemented that, but I am now running into an issue where LaTex is counting by twos.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.csv}
    Col1,Col2,Col3
    34,54,14
    63,40,93
    39,56,88
    15,42,85
    49,10,16
    89,94,59
    42,79,76
    42,90,35
    13,53,13
    10,60,37
    29,38,34
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\let\c@table\c@figure
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Sample 1}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \caption{This should be table 1}
        \label{This should be table 1}
        \csvreader[
        longtable=lrrrr,
    table head=
    \toprule\bfseries Col1 &\bfseries Col2 &\bfseries  Col3\\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
    ]{dummy.csv}{1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \caption{This should be table 2}
    \label{This should be table 2}
    \csvreader[
    longtable=lrrrr,
    table head=
    \toprule\bfseries Col4 &\bfseries Col5 &\bfseries  Col6\\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
    ]{dummy.csv}{1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}\label{section 2}
\subsection{sample 2}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \caption{This should be table 3}
    \label{This should be table 3}
    \csvreader[
    longtable=lrrrr,
    table head=
    \toprule\bfseries Col7 &\bfseries Col8 &\bfseries  Col9\\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
    ]{dummy.csv}{1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your use of [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable). A `longtable` is meant to be used as a non-float, since it's set on one page, and should roll over to subsequent pages. Using them includes the use of a `\caption`, necessarily. So, even though you don't include a `\caption` as part of the `longtable` (stemming from `\csvreader[longtable=..., ...]`), it increments the `figure` counter.

Since it's not possible to have a `longtable` work as expected inside a float, it's better to use the `tabular` option:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.csv}
    Col1,Col2,Col3
    34,54,14
    63,40,93
    39,56,88
    15,42,85
    49,10,16
    89,94,59
    42,79,76
    42,90,35
    13,53,13
    10,60,37
    29,38,34
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\let\c@table\c@figure
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be table 1}
  \csvreader[
    tabular=lrrrr,
    table head=
      \toprule\bfseries Col1 & \bfseries Col2 & \bfseries  Col3 \\ \midrule
      \bottomrule,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
  ]{dummy.csv}
    {1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be table 2}
  \csvreader[
    tabular=lrrrr,
    table head=
      \toprule\bfseries Col4 & \bfseries Col5 & \bfseries  Col6 \\ \midrule
      \bottomrule,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
  ]{dummy.csv}
    {1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be table 3}
  \csvreader[
    tabular=lrrrr,
    table head=
      \toprule\bfseries Col7 & \bfseries Col8 & \bfseries  Col9 \\ \midrule
      \bottomrule,
    late after line=\\,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
  ]{dummy.csv}
    {1=\One,2=\Two, 3=\Three}{\One & \Two & \Three}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also remove the `\endhead` and `\endfoot` definitions inside `table head` and `late after line`.